# Does the kernel keep track of socket addresses?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, tcp

When I call `accept` to get a connecting socket, I can get the address of the connection.
E.g.

```
sockaddr_in addr;
socklen_t addr_size = sizeof(addr);
const int sock = ::accept(main_socket, (sockaddr*)&addr, &addr_size);

// addr.sin_addr stores the address

char addr_str[256];
inet_ntop(addr.sin_family, &addr.sin_addr, addr_str, sizeof(addr_str));
```

But does the kernel retain the address associated with the socket?
Say I don't save the `addr` struct and only save `sock`, is there a function I can call to get the address later?

Comment: The function is `getpeername()`. You can also see it on the terminal with `netstat`.